# Is it normal if I have table with have no relationship with other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, erd

I have an existing application. Now my boss wants me to create a FAQ for apps usage documentation.

So I create tbl_faq. But tbl_faq doesn't have any relationship with others table.

```
tbl_faq
id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
title varchar(255) NOT NULL
content text NOT NULL
created DATETIME
```

But, I have some doubt in my mind when I see the final ERD diagram (using Workbench). Because I have 1 weird table which doesn't have any relationship at all.

My question: is this normal or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it has no relationship to anything but the application as a whole. This is is a fairly normal situation.

One way you could tie it in is if you link this to the user that created it, as that might be useful information, or if you can think of any other sorts of relationships that this data would naturally have.

Comment: only admin allow to create faq. so its useless to give it additional column to log who created that faq. Anyway. the answer is normal right?

Comment: It's not uncommon to have more than one admin. I do like to keep tabs on these things so that if there's ever any question as to "Who made that?" there's an easy answer. You'll find "orphan" tables like this fairly often, yes.

Comment: yup i agree on that case. thanks @tadman . you make me confident now. i will check this after several minutes (SO rule)

Answer (score 0):

It is always possible to think of potential new features. Suppose you want to tag and search the faq. Then you could add a tbl_tag entity which is a list of unique words, and a many-to-many relation between the tbl_tag entity and the tbl_faq entity.